# Issues installing python mplcursors

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplcursors

I tried to install mplcursers to my PC.
I tried:

```
pip install mplcursors
```

It gave me error as:

```
Collecting mplcursors
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mplcursors (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mplcursors
```

I also tried:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/anntzer/mplcursors
```

It gave me error as:

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/anntzer/mplcursors
Cloning https://github.com/anntzer/mplcursors to /tmp/pip-VP7mtD-build
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-VP7mtD-build/setup.py", line 1, in <module>
    from setupext import find_packages, setup
  File "setupext.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pathlib import Path
ImportError: No module named pathlib

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-VP7mtD-build/
```

Anyone has idea how I can solve the issue and install the mplcursors?

Comment: Which matplotlib version do you have installed?  Did you try upgrading to the latest?  Which python version are you using?

Comment: my matplotlib version is 3.3.4,  I just installed it recently

Comment: Something seems to be very wrong with your Python installation.  In any case, mplcursors consists of just 2 python files (https://github.com/anntzer/mplcursors/tree/master/lib/mplcursors), which in an extreme case you could copy to your local directory and use them directly.

Comment: copy which 2 files?   mlpcursor.py and pick_info.py?

Comment: Indeed.  It would only be a temporary solution. The real thing would probably be to fully reinstall Python.

Comment: I always recommend the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) for a completely reproducible environment. See the [mplcursors tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mplcursors/info) for links to installing mplcursors

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
!pip install plotly
```

It is working for me hope will work for you as well

Answer (score 0):

I was having the similar problems but a more useful error message:

```
Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/70/11/26f6016ff1ed7c43b5ee51793ac9f9d14ea7f5af8e2ecf9703d8bb88c96b/mplcursors-0.5.3.tar.gz (from https://pypi.org/simple/mplcursors/) (requires-python:>=3.7): Requested mplcursors from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/70/11/26f6016ff1ed7c43b5ee51793ac9f9d14ea7f5af8e2ecf9703d8bb88c96b/mplcursors-0.5.3.tar.gz has inconsistent version: expected '0.5.3', but metadata has '0.0.0'
  Using cached mplcursors-0.5.2.tar.gz (89 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

I ran

```
  python -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver mplcursors
```

And it fixed it